# Power Circuit for Raspberry pi portable

Tags: batteries, raspberry-pi

I am building a hand held portable raspberry pi. I have just plugging the battery in and using the thing, but I want to make the battery completely part of the unit without the need to unplug it when i am done. so here is what i want to do completely:

1. Have a switch to be the master on/off switch.
2. when the unit is plugged in to a dc power source (wall wart), you will have a switch that will let you to select between powering the unit or charge the unit
3. Have led indicators for charging, unit powered by battery, unit powered by external

here is what i have come up with already

[image]

let me know where i need to go from here

Clarifications:

1. the 7.4 v battery has a output of 2 A and it has a charging PCB built int the battery (which is why i bought this one)
2. I have been using the pi with this setup less the switched for about a month no issues. Since i wanted to add in switches and led indicators AND i am just a novice on building circuits, i don't know if what i have the switches right
3. I am using a variable switching regulator that will work down to 5.5 v and it works perfect with little current usage.

Comment: what you want is a 2-cell lithium ion charging circuit with on/off switch and the ability to power the system through the charger unit too.

Comment: and that goes off to the 5V 1A LDO regulator

Comment: or do single cell with boost converter as Ignacio suggests below! He's a good man

Comment: If you use a LM7805 or similar to regulate the 7.4V to 5V, it might get hot. Don't forget to add a heatsink just in case or be prepared to burn the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Going with a single cell and a boost regulator will simplify charging by removing the need to balance the cells. Additionally you should consider adding a battery charger chip that allows you to charge from USB or 7-19V power bricks while also powering the system.

Answer (score 0):

I like what you got there. Maybe a little higher voltage battery, depending on its voltage/discharge curve. 7.4V is usually around the min for stable regulation with 5V ss regulators with any current draw as i remember.

Comment: 7V is minimum, so 7.4 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a higher voltage battery (a 3S 11.1V battery for example) because the 7.4V battery has an operating voltage of around 6V (dead) to 8.4V (fully charged).

When the battery voltage drops below 7V any switching circuitry will drop in efficiency/stability as the other answers mentioned.